# Has anyone had any success using Hudson (or another similar build system) with Perl?

Tags: perl, jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson, build-automation

Has anyone had any success using Hudson (or another similar build system) with Perl?

Comment: What problem are you running into?

Comment: 'with Perl' means your builds are run by a perl script?   Or do you want to do something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For non-Java build scripts, I usually use Hudson's custom build script template. That is, I can specify a shell script in Hudson. From there, I can run GNU tools like make, configure, and I usually embed some echo's into the script, or redirect some output to a custom file, which I then package up in a special folder, and mark as a build artifact.

For example, I might,

```
cd src
perl Makefile.PL > ${WORKSPACE}/logs/makefile.log
make > ${WORKSPACE}/logs/make.log
```

for starters.

Then I could wrap up logs/** as build artifacts.

Answer (score 3):

I've integrated Perl into several build systems, although not Hudson. Why do you want to use Hudson? Maybe there's another answer to your problem.

- Are you in a Java shop that uses Hudson for everything else?
- Is there some feature in Hudson that you really want?
- Are you avoiding other build systems for some reason?

Comment: Would you like to recommend one that works better? Hudson seems to work very well from my experience using it with Perl.

Comment: Works better for what? That's why I'm trying to clarify the question.

Answer (score 3):

Having used Hudson and Java for a year or so, and Hudson and Perl for a few months, my preferance is for the former, and to make the latter behave liek the former.

Hudson is Java-centric, and works best out-of-the-box with Maven and Junit. However, it supports shell scripts, so you can easily do the usual `perl Makefile.PL && make && make test`.

You can get much nicer results, though, if you use oen of the (newish) Perl test-result formatters:

```
perl Makefile.PL
make setup
prove --timer --recurse -m --harness=TAP::Harness::JUnit t/
```

The use of

```
TAP::Harness::JUnit
```

will integrate the Perl test results into Hudson, allowing Hudson to graph and report as if you were running a Java project.

You can easily surround the `prove` line with calls to start/stop an Apache test server - see CPAN for Apache Test.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, someone has had success with another similar build system.